# MATLAB combine two avi. together

Tags: matlab, animation, avi

I created two avi. file and they have the same length.
I wanted to combine them on a same background and one on top another one on the bottom.
The code I used for one of the animation is below, the other one is similar.
Is there any way I can do that?

```
load Results.mat;
I = imread('hex08.jpg');
[rows,columns,numberOfColorChannels] = size(I);
if numberOfColorChannels >1
    I = I(:,:,2);
end
background = imresize(background, [rows,columns]);


figure(1);
hold on;
for i=1:500
    A=angle(i,:);

    J = imrotate(I,A,'crop');
    mask = J == 0;
    mask = bwareafilt(mask,4);
    J(mask) = background(mask);
    pause(0.01)
    imshow(J);
    imwrite(J,[num2str(i),'.png']);

end


imageNames = dir(fullfile('*.png'));
imageNames = {imageNames.name}';

outputVideo = VideoWriter(fullfile('hex08.avi'));
outputVideo.FrameRate = 15;
open(outputVideo)

for ii = 1:length(imageNames)
   img = imread(fullfile(imageNames{ii}));
   writeVideo(outputVideo,img)
end

close(outputVideo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way this can be done:
Just like you read the image into `img`, you can read a second image (from the second video) into `img2`. Then, you can create a combined image of the two: `imgCombined = [img ; img2];` which will contain the first image on top and the second on bottom (This will work if both images are the same width, otherwise you will need to resize/crop). When you write to the video file, use `writeVideo(outputVideo,imgCombined)`.